# Setting Macro Variable equal to value in table

Tags: sas

I have a table with one row and 4 columns. I would like to create 4 macro variables named after each column where the value is set to the value in the 1 row.

If this were R I could access the values directly with something like:

```
newvar1=tablename[1,1]
newvar2=tablename[1,2]...
```

Is there anyway for me to select values from a table and set macrovariables equal to that value?

So something like:

```
%macrovar1=tablename[1,1]...
```

Except obviously the right side of the equals sign is R code not SAS.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways, but the simplest is:

```
data _null_;
  set have;
  if _n_=1 then do;
    call symputx('macrovar1',var1);
   *more of these;
  end;
  stop;
run;
```

That opens the dataset, then if on first row (`_n_` is iteration of data step loop, which in most cases is the first row), use [call symputx](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002295697.htm) to assign its value to a macro variable.

I would note that you should remember that SAS macro variables are not data variables, do not have a data type (always are text), and *usually* are not used to store data the way you would use vectors in R.

Comment: I think this is the right idea, but it isn't doing what I want. For example, let's say one of my columns is called first name, and the value in the one row is Jim. I want to create a macrovariable like "%fname=Jim" so that I can then later in the program set variables equal to &fname, and get Jim. What it does now is append the fname column with no values. So if I write "data something;set table; var=&fname;run;" I get a new column named Jim with no values, instead of having var=Jim.

Comment: @Carl Sounds like you may be trying to use the macro variable value within the same datastep where you assigned a value to it.  Is this right?  Can you perhaps create a new question with a specific example that shows the code not behaving as intended?

Comment: You want the value of Jim, or the variable named Jim?  If you want the value of Jim, it is `var="&fname.";` since it's text.  Like I said - this isn't a vector, like in [tag:r].  This is text, as if you'd typed it in by hand.  Odds are good there's a better way to do this than using a macro variable, depending on what exactly you're doing.

Comment: I got it to work. I had some separate mistakes that caused the problem. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 4):

You can use proc sql to do it like so:

```
proc sql noprint inobs=1;
  select name into :my_val from sashelp.class;
quit;
%put &my_val;
```

Or you can use `call symput` from the datastep like this:

```
data _null_;
  set sashelp.class(obs=1);
  call symput('my_val',name);
run;
```

For something more flexibile, we use a utility macro that allows us to check values from anywhere in our code.  I've modified it slightly to accommodate your request but the usage will be like this:

```
%let my_val = %get_val(iDs=sashelp.class, iField=name);
```

You could also use it in the middle of a proc or a datastep like so:

```
data _null_;
  my_value = "%get_val(iDs=sashelp.class, iField=name)";
run;
```

Or even:

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table want as
  select * from sashelp.class
  where name = "%get_val(iDs=sashelp.class, iField=name)"
  ;
quit;
```

Here is the macro definition:

```
%macro get_val(iDs=, iField=);
  %local dsid pos rc result cnt value;

  %let result=;
  %let cnt=0;

  /*
  ** ENSURE ALL THE REQUIRED PARAMETERS WERE PASSED IN.
  */
  %if "&iDs" ne "" and "&iField" ne "" %then %do;

    %let dsid=%sysfunc(open(&iDs,i));
    %if &dsid %then %do;

      %let pos=%sysfunc(varnum(&dsid,&iField));
      %if &pos %then %do;

        %let rc=%sysfunc(fetch(&dsid));

        %if "%sysfunc(vartype(&dsid,&pos))" = "C" %then %do;
          %let value = %qsysfunc(getvarc(&dsid,&pos));
          %if "%trim(&value)" ne "" %then %do;
            %let value = %qtrim(&value);
          %end;
        %end;
        %else %do;
          %let value = %sysfunc(getvarn(&dsid,&pos));
        %end;
        &value

      %end;
      %else %do;
        %put ERROR: MACRO.GET_VAL.SAS: FIELD &iField NOT FOUND IN DATASET %upcase(&iDs).;
      %end;
    %end;
    %else %do;
      %put ERROR: MACRO.GET_VAL.SAS: DATASET %upcase(&iDs) COULD NOT BE OPENED.;
    %end;

    %let rc=%sysfunc(close(&dsid));

  %end;
  %else %do;
    %put ERROR: MACRO.GET_VAL.SAS: YOU MUST SPECIFY BOTH THE IDS AND IFIELD PARAMETERS TO CALL THIS MACRO.;
  %end;

%mend;
```

The above macro is an abbreviated version of the %ds2list macro found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27530850/a-macro-function-to-produce-a-macro-variable-from-a-data-variable/27534052#27534052).

Comment: I'm just going to add that my preferred way out of the above approaches is to use the `%let =` approach, as this is both more concise, and clearer in its intention (ie. it is clear that all the code is doing is setting a value to a macro variable, this is not as clear with a `data` step or `proc sql` statement).  That is the reason why I've added the 3rd macro approach.  Most people settle for the data step or proc sql however.